# Cors error happening on a simplejwt authenticated webpage

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-cors-headers

I have used simplejwt in my code and I also have added django-cors-headers to my project to allow frontend development. the problem is that I have 2 APIs that need authentication to allow users to work with them and I can not send a request to these two APIs on the front end and I get the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/myapi' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-auth-token is not allowed by Access-Coontrol-Allow-Headers in preflight response
```

Here are the important parts of my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),  
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=10),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=10),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'userID',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
}
```

and here are my views.py and serializers.py

```
# Serializers.py
class myAPISerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = someModel
        fields = ('user', 'someField',)
        read_only_fields = ('user',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ... #Some changes
        return super().create(validated_data)

# Views.py
class PaymentView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PaymentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Payment.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According django-cors-headers documentation:

> CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before
> any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s
> CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise’s WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not
> before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these
> responses.

So just add it at the top of your list, like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...,
]
```

Comment: it was actually an error on the frontend, but thanks for the tip anyway!!

Comment: @MohsenAmiri would be great if you shared what was causing the error

Comment: @MohsenAmiri can you please share how you fixed it in your frontend?